Motivation for Tensor Product of Modules
How did the motivation and background for the definition of the tensor product in modules arise, and what was the process of abstraction that led to the formation of the definition of the tensor product in modules?

It is a natural generalization of the tensor product of vector spaces and of abelian groups, as well as a natural generalization of the process of taking the intersection of two subvarieties of an algebraic variety, or of two ideals. I don't know who specifically to credit with the definition.
